# Where i Can Find the Package.resolved in React-Native Project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

i need to delete my Package.resoleved. usually it should be in

[appName].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved

but I don't have the "swiftpm" folder in my react-project. i DOn't know how to find it

Comment: React native uses cocoapods for dependencies, there's no Package.resolved file. https://www.codementor.io/blog/swift-package-manager-5f85eqvygj Alternatively, you can delete the Podfile.lock file and Pods folder and re-run pod install

Answer (score 0):

if find it.
it is in inside the foulder ios. in the foulder

/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved

NOT inside .xcodeproj

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).